# Is there dplyr support for any jdbc compliant database?

Tags: r, jdbc, dplyr

I was trying to use dplyr in an environment where we have a set of JDBC compliant databases and I need to support all of them. Instead of adding data sources for each of them, it made sense to see if something is available for using JDBC drivers to make database connections and run queries.

Below are the things I have tried,

1. I tried to get dplyrJDBC package to work - https://github.com/jimhester/dplyrJDBC.
   I kept getting the error "dbi_connect" not found.
2. Followed Hadley's comment thread on this issue - https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/329
   Where he explains how to add a new data source to dplyr.

If I understood it correctly, the dbi_connect method needs to be implemented for whichever new datasource is to be added. So either the dplyrJDBC package is missing something or something incorrect in the way I am installing it?

If the dplyrJDBC option doesn't work out, is there a way for me to connect to any JDBC compliant database and use dplyr or just adding each of the data source my only option?

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of setting the JDBC connection to use the Oracle translation in `dbplyr`.  You can change it to the database you need translation for.  These lines should go at the top of the R script:

```
sql_translate_env.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translate_env.Oracle
sql_select.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_subquery.Oracle
```